# Testing convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \ln(n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Apply the Integral Test:
$$\int_1^\infty \ln(x + 1) ~dx.$$
Let $t=x+1$, $dt = dx$:
$$\int_1^\infty \ln(x+1) ~dx = \int_2^\infty \ln t ~dt.$$
Integrate by parts:
$$dv = dt; \quad v=t; $$
$$u = \ln t; \quad du= 1/t ~dt.$$
\begin{align*}
\int u ~dv & = uv - \int v ~du \\
\int \ln t ~dt & = t \ln t - \int t \cdot \frac{1}{t} ~dt \\
 & = t \ln t  - t \\
 & = (x+1) \ln(x+1) - (x+1).
\end{align*}
At the upper limit infinity, the integral diverges to infinity.

Therefore, the series diverges as well.

Is my procedure correct?

Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Kindly refer here (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/) on how to typeset (i.e. how to write equations etc) on this website. Typesetting makes it easier to read.

Comment: Also, did you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log(n+1)$ or $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log((n+1)/n)$?

Comment: @Henry T. Horton: Great work!

Comment: Remember that if the terms of a series don't go to zero, the series can't converge. The integral test also comes with conditions which you haven't checked.

Comment: You could also notice that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log(n+1) = \log((n+1)!)$.

Comment: The upper limit of my summation should be $N$, of course. And the $n$ in the factorial should be $N$. Oops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see no problems assuming you kept track of your bounds of integration properly. However, you do not need to do the integral test to see that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \ln(n+1)$ diverges. If it were to converge, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \ln(n+1)=0$ but this is clearly not the case.